# ascii art using letter in javascript

Tags: javascript, ascii-art

Create a program that translates the input (any combination of X, Y, or Z) to their low-resolution
ascii art-like representation (use letter ‘O’ as the character to draw the letters).

Input Parameters:

- letters - any combination of the letters X, Y, and Z (example: XYZ, ZXY, ZZXXXYYYYY)
- size - block size of each letter; odd numbers, greater than or equal to 3 (example: 3, 5, 7, 9… etc)
- direction - horizontal or vertical

more for a beginner coding and i could not find any refence other reference ive found is make image into ascii art and it would be helpful if it could be explained every part.thank you